# Has anyone used The Graph before? I am having trouble creating a SubGraph

Tags: solidity, thegraph

I am trying to create a **SubGraph** using an existing contract, but I keep getting the error:

```html
 Load subgraph from subgraph.yaml

✖ Failed to load subgraph from subgraph.yaml: Error in subgraph.yaml:



Path: dataSources > 0 > mapping > entities

No value provided

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

In the `subgraph.yaml` file, it says I don't have any entities, and I think this is triggering the error. However, I couldn't find any documentation on why this error occurred or how SubGraphs were created.

- For reference, I believe that the error is caused by my contract ABI. I am currently passing in an ABI from one solidity class file, but my project consists of other sol files. I am not sure how you would create an ABI file for all the solidity files.
- Also, The Graph was not able to get the ABI files directly through etherscan, so I had to pass them in locally.